# Ways to Create Instance

Tags: swift

I have a Class like this:

```
class TestClass {
    let str = "string"
}
```

Now, I know two ways to create an instance.

First way:

```
let firstTestInstance: TestClass!
firstTestInstance = TestClass()
```

Second way:

```
let secondTestInstance = TestClass()
```

I want to know:

- What is the difference between the first way and the second way?
- Which is better? Why?
- Are there are other ways to create Instance?

PS: I saw the Swift Document use second way.

Comment: The second way is simply a combining the first two lines of the first way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to understand the difference between **declaring** a variable/constant and **initializing** a variable/constant.

**Declaring** a variable tells Swift that you are adding a new variable.

A variable (`var`) or constant (`let`) declaration looks like this:

```
let firstTestInstance: TestClass
```

Here, we have declared a constant called `firstTestInstance` with a type of `TestClass`.

**Initializing** a variable assigns an initial value to that variable.

The initialization of an already-declared variable or constant looks like this:

```
firstTestInstance = TestClass()
```

Here, we are creating a new instance of `TestClass` and assigning it as the initial value of `firstTestInstance`.

It is also possible to combine both of these steps in a single line:

```
let firstTestInstance: TestClass = TestClass()
```

Because it is obvious from this line that the type of the constant is `TestClass`, we may exclude the type annotation:

```
let firstTestInstance = TestClass()
```

Here, Swift is able to infer the type of `firstTestInstance`. This is called *type inference*.

### The second way you asked about

I'll get to your first example, but your second one is easier to explain.

You posted the following:

```
let secondTestInstance = TestClass()
```

Here, you are combining the declaration with the initialization. The type of `secondTestInstance` is inferred to be `TestClass`.

### The first way you asked about

You posted the following:

```
let firstTestInstance: TestClass!
firstTestInstance = TestClass()
```

One might say this does exactly the same thing as your second example but just in two separate steps. Ordinarily, this would be correct, but it is not correct this time because of the `!` after `TestClass`. Those two lines are equivalent to the following single line:

```
let firstTestInstance: TestClass! = TestClass()
```

Here, if Swift were to attempt to infer the type of `firstTestInstance` by itself, it would infer a type of `TestClass`. But here, you are providing a type annotation telling Swift that the type should actually be `TestClass!`, which is a different type from simply `TestClass`.

Basically, by appending a `!` to the end of a type annotation, you are saying that the type is actually an **implicitly unwrapped optional `TestClass`**.

Optionals (including implicitly unwrapped ones) are described in "Optionals" in [The Basics section of The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) guide.

## Which is better?

Ignoring the fact that your first example uses an implicitly unwrapped optional and instead focusing only on whether it's better to use 1 line or 2, the answer is it depends. If you can do it on 1 line, go ahead. It's cleaner that way. However, there may be some cases where you'll need to do it in two separate lines, such as in the following example:

```
let myConstant: String
if boolVariable {
    myConstant = "hello"
} else {
    myConstant = "world"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The first way first declares the constant to be of the TextClass type and then sets it to TestClass on the second line.

As Davy said, the second line just combines the two, declaring and setting the constant as TestClass.

Which is better? I'm not sure there's any real difference between the two ways so I prefer to use the second method as it helps make the code look a bit cleaner using only one line instead of two.

Comment: That would be the case if it wasn't for the `!` in the first one.